# How to only download the most recent emails on Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I just downloaded Thunderbird and signed into my email however it started downloading emails from 2005. I only want to download/sync the most recent emails. I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have too many emails and it will take way too long to download all the emails from 2005. Please help :)

Comment: Not sure if this works for you: [download only recent mails in Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/a/143017/1086345). It seems it only works IMAP accounts

Comment: You need to use IMAP. POP3 is dangerous.